# Show data from Firebase in a Recyclerview in a Fragment | Java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

How can I take data from Firebase into a recyclerview and show it inside a fragment?

I followed [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBgXVGgTaHk&list=PPSV&ab_channel=Foxandroid) video to create a recyclerview inside a fragment. But in it the data is static. (retrieved from the strings file)

I then tried to incorporate [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8sKwoVjqU0&ab_channel=Foxandroid) video to retrieve data from Firebase.

But it doesn't work. Maybe I have to call the functions in a different override??

---

My Fragment Class (HomeFragemnt.java)

```
package com.example.foodapp.deliverer;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.foodapp.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<OrderItem> orderItemArrayList;
    RecyclerView recyclerview;
    DatabaseReference DB;
    ItemRecyclerAdapter itemRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.delivery_fragment_home, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        recyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.delivery_orders_recyclerView);
        DB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Delivery");
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        orderItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemRecyclerAdapter = new ItemRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), orderItemArrayList);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(itemRecyclerAdapter);

        DB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    OrderItem item = dataSnapshot.child("Delivery").getValue(OrderItem.class);
                    orderItemArrayList.add(item);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        itemRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

---

My Fragment Layout (delivery_fragment_home.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".deliverer.HomeFragment" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/delivery_orders_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        android:background="#CDDC39"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/delivery_orderitem" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

Item into Recyclerview class (OrderItem.java)

```
package com.example.foodapp.deliverer;

public class OrderItem {
    private String orderID;
    private String Address;

    public OrderItem(String orderID, String Address) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
        this.Address = Address;
    }

    public String getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }
}
```

---

Item into recyclerview layout (delivery_orderItem.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_orderId"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_address"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_orderId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/lbl_orderId"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_orderId" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

Adapter class (ItemRecyclerAdapter.java)

```
package com.example.foodapp.deliverer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.foodapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ItemRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecyclerAdapter.DriverItemViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<OrderItem> itemArrayList;

    public ItemRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<OrderItem> itemList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemArrayList = itemList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DriverItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.delivery_orderitem, parent, false);
        return new DriverItemViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemRecyclerAdapter.DriverItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        OrderItem order = itemArrayList.get(position);
        holder.orderID.setText(order.getOrderID());
        holder.address.setText(order.getAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemArrayList .size();
    }


    public static class DriverItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView orderID;
        private TextView address;


        public DriverItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.orderID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_orderId);
            this.address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_address);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: notify adapter inside onDataChange method.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try looking at [Show Firebase Database Data into a RecyclerView ListView Tutorial](https://www.android-examples.com/show-firebase-database-data-into-recyclerview/?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=957268A9C63744F0A364AA21405F061A).